# JS arrays: merging together following items that starts by the same char (refer to the next loop in for loop)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, merge

Basically I have an item with HTML tags in it, the problem is that I have some instructions starting by an @ in this array too. Here's what the array looks like:

```
store = ["@if str == 'hello'", "<div>", "<h1>hello world</h1>", "</div>", "@else", "<p>Hello</p>"]
```

I want to group every HTML tags between the instruction items into one array item, resulted like this:

```
store = ["@if str == 'hello'", "<div><h1>hello world</h1></div>", "@else", "<p>Hello</p>"]
```

So I ended up with this code:

```
const store = ["@if str == 'hello'", "<div>", "<h1>hello world</h1>", "</div>", "@else", "<p>Hello</p>"]
const merged = [];

for (let i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
    if(store[i].slice(0, 1) == "@"){
        merged.push(store[i]);
    } else if (store[i].slice(0, 1) == "<") {
        while (store[i+1] == "<") {
            str = store[i] + store[i+1];
            merged.push(str)
        }
    }
}
console.log(merged);
```

But it's working, I guess because of the "[i+1]" that I use on the store array.

Comment: It doesn't work because `store[i+1] == "<"` this checks if the entire string is `<` not just the beginning. But fixing it will cause infinite loop, because you don't increment `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have another variable store the accumulating element string, then push it when you it another condition.

```js
const store = ["@if str == 'hello'", "<div>", "<h1>hello world</h1>", "</div>", "@else", "<p>Hello</p>"]
const merged = [];
let current = [];

for (let i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
    if(store[i].slice(0, 1) == "@"){
        if(current.length) merged.push(current.join(''))
        current = []
        merged.push(store[i]);
    } else if (store[i].slice(0, 1) == "<") {
       current.push(store[i])
    }
}
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Anytime! You too :)